# Parameter added to model but not shown on the page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am trying to make my first web project using Spring MVC.
I have problem when i try to show variables that has been put into my model. 
But on my page see my test parameter, but my table is empty.
Please, tell me, what i missed.

Im using tiles controller, so here is my tile of home.jsp where i want to show my list:

```
<div id="indexLeftColumn">
<div id="welcomeText">
    <p>[ cool picture ]</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="indexRightColumn">
<div id="deviceList">
    Table with list of devices</br>
    ${blah}
     <table class="table" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Device ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${hubsIDList}" var="hub" >
                    <tr>

                        <td>${hub}</td>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
</table>
</div>


</div>
```

Here is part of my controller which adds values and returns my home.jsp
I added new parameter "blah" just to test, that parameters not disappear elsewhere

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model) {
    log.info("Loading homepage");
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    ArrayList<String> hubsID =(ArrayList<String>) userDetails.getParameter("hubsID"); //checked - it's not empty and truly Array list of Strings
    model.addAttribute("hubsIDList",hubsID);  
    model.addAttribute("blah","Test if parameters still here"); //added for test that my parameters aren't dissapear
    return "home";
}
```

And here is my includes

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="spring_form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="sec" %>
```

**UPD**
Tried to use controller metod as below, but still no result - test parameter is visible on page, but table is empty

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView  home(Model model) {
    HashMap<String,Object> modelParams = (HashMap)model.asMap();
    log.info("Loading homepage");
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    ArrayList<String> hubsID =(ArrayList<String>) userDetails.getParameter("hubsID");
    modelParams.put("hubsIDList",hubsID);
    modelParams.put("blah","Test if parameters still here");

    return new ModelAndView("home",modelParams);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "that parameters not disappear elsewhere", you are saying that the parameter is not being displayed in the page ?

Comment: yes, it's not displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is somewhere in my tiles controller. Somehow my taglibs was not connected to my home.jsp tile so my c: tags was unusable.
  If i use taglib directly in my jsp - all is works.

Hope this will help someone with same problem.

Thanx @Koitoer for helping me in my tries.